# Alert is not working for single digits

Tags: javascript

Here is my code below:

```
if (document.getElementById('actual').value < document.getElementById('min').value
    || document.getElementById('actual').value > document.getElementById('max').value) {
    alert("not in range");
}
```

This alert works for digits from 10 to 100 or more.

Suppose `min` value is 0 and `max` value is 10 and `actual` is 9; then this alert does not work, and it starts showing alerts like 'not in range',  even though the actual value is in range.

There are 3 editable text boxes in a JSP file:  **min, max and actual**. When the user enter the values in text box, I check the values using the above code.

Comment: Strings compare alphabetically, unlike numbers.

Comment: This reads more like a JavaScript issue than a JSP issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById('actual').value) < parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value)
|| parseInt(document.getElementById('actual').value) > parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value))
{ 
    alert("not in range");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Makoto and Jonny Grisham sir, Now alert working fine

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the solution that Jonny Grisham has suggested; it simply moves the values into easier-to-read variables and overall reduces the length of that particular line.  It also makes use of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
var actual = parseInt(document.getElementById('actual').value);
var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);

if(actual < min || actual > max) {
    alert('not in range');
}
```

Be very careful that the value inside of those IDs is actually numeric.  There are conditions in which [you will get `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Examples) (as in, it's not a number), or where you'll get a result in which you didn't expect (such as `parseInt("12number127")` will result in `12`).

Comment: Thank you very much Makoto and Jonny Grisham sir, Now alert working fine